# Posting to a web service - 400 error

Tags: c#, web-services

I have checked related posts on stackoverflow but they haven't helped my problem.

I am having trouble posting data to a customer's web service. I cannot tell whether it is a code defiency or some problem at the server end. The response we get is a httpWebException with the message "The server returned an error (400) Bad request", and the httpWebException Status has a value of ProtocolError.

The payload is a chunk of XML, and the request ContentType is "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'". It's also described as a RESTful web service.

Here, in case it offers some illumination, is the actual C# code:

```
        XDocument xmlResponse = null;
        //Post the xml to the web service
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
        byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlRecord.ToString());
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        //retrieve the response from the web service
        Trace.Log("Examining web service response");
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                    xmlResponse = XDocument.Parse(responseStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        var m = wex.Message;
        throw wex;
    }
```

Can anyone suggest what is causing the problem? For example, have I failed to set some additional property on the httprequest? Is the ContentType inappropriate for posting? I should add that fetching data from the same web service, using almost identical code (except that the method is set to "POST") works perfectly. The problem only arises when posting XML back to the web service. (The XML is a copy of the documented XML structure so I don't think the problem lies with that.)

TIA

Comment: How can we tell what the endpoint is doing here?

Comment: can you try like `request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml";`.

Comment: I've now tried that change - sadly no improvement. davidG - I can't tell what the web service is doing, that's half my problem. I don't know if my code is deficient or the web service is. I've also asked the customer to try to trap the http request at the server end and tell me what their web service doesn't like about it, but no luck so far. I'm hoping there is something wrong or missing about my code, because that will be the simple solution for me.

Comment: It turned out (after a long struggle) that the XML definitions we had been given were incorrect, so the submitted XML was wrong.